# Toggling right-arrow to down arrow in jquery [accordion-like]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have designed a sort of accordion. When I click on the right-arrow of an item, say `Area A`, it toggles to give me the list of item in `Area A` and at the same time, the arrow-right goes down (Like this: ▼). When I click it again, the list hides and the arrow becomes in arrow-right again. Note that in `Area A`, I will have a sub list. Can someone help me to achieve this ?

►  Area A

►  Area B

►  Area C

If I click on Area A -->

▼ Area A
 - Item 1 
 - Item 2
►  Area B
►  Area C

```
  <ul style="list-style: none;">
    <div ng-repeat="area in areas">     
      <div class="arrow-up" style="float:left;"> &#9658; </div>                                     
          <li> {{area}} </li>
    <div ng-repeat="x in lists">
      <li style="display: none;"> {{x}} </li>               
    </div>
       <div style="display: none;" class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
    </div>  
</ul>
```

**myjs**

```
$(#arrow-up').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("arrow-down");
});
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: if you add your controller in a code pen I can help you more easily

Comment: a suggestion would be to ng-hide'"somevariable" then toggle that variable on click

Comment: A `div` is not allowed as direct descendant of a `ul`. Then, about the rotations, look for CSS [`transform: rotate(xdeg)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate). Just toggling classes will do.

Comment: I was trying to use jquery.. Is it possible to do this with angular?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about this:

```
$('.arrow-right').click(function(){    // But isn't it an arrow right??
                                       // And should be a class.
  $(this).toggleClass("arrow-down");
});
```

You just miss the CSS ?

This will do:

```
.arrow-down{
  transform: rotate(90deg);  /* 90 degres rotation */
}
```

Comment: No effect. not even on the click.

Comment: Is it possible with Angular rather than using Jquery? Just curious :)

Comment: I'm not used to Angular... Maybe. But from what I know, Angular is more data oriented than element manipulations. Now Check if you use the `id` multiple times... It better should be a class. I edited.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you provide an input please ?

Comment: From your HTML, which I repeat, is invalid... It looks like you have to use `.arrow-up` as a selector for the click handler. But if I were you, I would rename them all to arrow-right. Significative names always help.